# Package managing distro iso images

Tags: package-manager

I have many distro images downloaded:

```
$ ls ~/distros  
archlinux-2023.04.01-x86_64.iso  
ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso  
Fedora-Workstation-Live-aarch64-38-1.6.iso  
...
```

Is there a tool for managing distros isos? e.g: new updates, go back to older version, different flavor, ... Something like

- `pacman-iso -Syu`: updates all isos in a pre-specified location.
- `pacman-iso -Ss archlinux`: Searches for all isos containing a keyword
- `pacman-iso ...etc`: grabbing latest distro torrent magnet link, etc...